# Why isn't there an official XML Schema for XHTML5?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml

Accorting to [this article](https://www.w3.org/blog/2008/01/html5-is-html-and-xml/), there are 2 flavors of HTML5: html and XML.
On W3 I can't find an official DTD or XML Schema. On the internet I only found unofficial ones.

So, how can I validate an XHTML5 document?

Comment: Is it a polyglot document?

Comment: You can just run it through the W3C validator (which will tell you if it's correct HTML5) and load it into a browser (which will tell you if it's well-formed XML) and then you'll know it's XHTML5.

Answer (score 2):

Re:

> Why isn't there an official XML Schema for XHTML5?

See [this comment on the v.Nu GitHub repo](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/251#issuecomment-192209209).

For further reading, see the [unsoup/validator GitHub repo](https://github.com/unsoup/validator).

Re:

> how can I validate an XHTML5 document?

Upload an XHTML5 document with the file extension `.xhtml` to an instance of the Nu Html Checker (v.Nu). For example:

https://html5.validator.nu/

To validate XHTML5 as you type ("on the fly"), consider using the Atom editor with the new [`linter-vnu`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-vnu) package (published today).

Answer (score 0):

While HTML 5 is based on HTML 4 and earlier, HTML 5 is not an SGML application ('application' is the term used for a language defined using SGML) and hence there is not a DTD, nor is it XML and hence there is no XSD for it.

HTML 5 is its own independent language.